# Running a bash file in a new terminal window and close the window when done

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I'd like to run a bash file on a darwin via:

```
open -n -a Terminal --args bashfile.sh
```

The bash file itself looks like:

```
#! /bin/sh
<application> <arguments>
```

It works as expected, but is there a way to **close the terminal window when the process is done**?

*I already tried `exit;` and `exit 0;` but without success.*

---

#### Partial solution

In the Terminal's preferences (*Terminal > Preferences > Settings > Shell*) you can set the 'When the shell exists' flag  to `close the window if the shell exited cleanly`. If nothing went wrong, this closes the terminal window afterwards, but not the application as such.

Answer (score 2):

If this is the only one terminal window, then you can try killing its process from script, which will terminate Terminal process and bash script running in it. The hardest part here is to determine right way to kill it that will work for you. The easiest way is to do:

`killall Terminal`

I guess multiple Terminal windows run in single process, so that means that you'll have all windows closed after this command.

If you are using other terminal emulator as your main tool (like iTerm), then it won't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks Pavel! But unfortunately this closes all terminal windows.

Answer (score 1):

You tag [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) but shebang points to `/bin/sh`. I assume `sh` is symlinked to `bash` in your system.

Try

```
kill $PPID
```

at the end of your script. As `$PPID` expands to the process ID of the shell parent, it should kill the right `Terminal` and leave other instances alone.

On my Ubuntu `Terminal` is GNUstep terminal emulator. I don't know how similar it is to yours.

Furthermore my `Terminal` (the package `terminal.app`, version `0.9.8-1+nmu1build1`, OS `Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS`) often misbehaves when it receives the signal from within the script; it hangs hopelessly. A bug, I guess. The only firm way to kill it is with force:

```
kill -SIGKILL $PPID
```

Comment: I think it's a specific osx thing. I'm sure that this will work on linux, but here something seems to block the kill command. The terminal window closes as expected, but the application is still running. Anyway, thanks Kamil!

Answer (score 0):

The Bash man page has a section on Special Parameters. The one you want is `$$`, which expands to the PID of the current shell.

`kill $$` should do what you want, though I'm on Win7 now and can't test it.

Comment: It returns *"Terminated"*, but leaves the window open. Thanks anyway.